# How do i write a simple If Else query with wmic.exe

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

i write a simple wmic.exe query:

if wmic product where "name like '%Adobe Reader%'" get version

Now i want to check, if Version equals 11.0.04

If Version eq 11.0.04 goto end

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wmic` example:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL 
for /f %%a in ('wmic product where 'name like "%%Adobe Reader%%"' get version /value^|find /i "Version"') do set "%%~a"
if defined Version (echo %Version%) else echo Adobe Reader not found!
if "%Version%"=="11.0.04" goto:eof
```

Comment: dont you need to escape the single quotes in for /f?

Comment: @npocmaka no, it's working. The syntax of `wmic` is curious. :)